# Horizontal barplot and average values (table)

Tags: r, bar-chart

So I have this data vectors, which represent average:

```
a1<-c(5.0, 4.0, 7.0, 5.3, 3.5)
names(a1)<-c(as.character(c("Power", "Strenght", "Price", "Perf.", "CCM")))
```

and this code to generate barplot

```
barplot(a1, main="Distribution",
        xlab="N", col=1:5,horiz=TRUE)
        legend("topright", 
        legend = names(a1), 
        fill = 1:5,
        cex = 0.75)
```

And my result is

[image]

Now I would like to know if there is a way, that I could edit my R code and get this as my output:

[image]

Picture above is print screen form one report I found on internet. So I would like to create these (or similar) plots and table of average values, where for example STRATEGIC PLANING SKILLS will present CCM and so fort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
df <- data.frame(x=names(a1), y=a1)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, fill=x)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+ coord_flip()+
  geom_text(aes(y=max(y)+0.5, label=y), color="black")+
  scale_fill_discrete(guide="none")+
  theme_bw()+theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
```

*Edit:* Response to OP's comment.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, fill=x)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+ coord_flip()+
  geom_text(aes(y=max(y)+0.5, label=y), color="black", hjust=0)+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="", guide=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using ggplot2 ?

Comment: Probably. If you change your question to specify that you want only  non-ggplot solutions, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: I am looking for options that are closest to the image above.  I am not very familiar with ggplot, but can I base on your code, insert in ggplot character name= AVERAGE, which I would include above average values in ggplot?

Comment: can you tell me based on your code, what I need to do, do delet names on the X-asis and put one name, and still have 5 bars?

Comment: @ jlhoward thanks. One more question, is it possible to also exclude legend on left, so that i would gave just barplot and average values, without any labels?

Comment: Yes but why would you do that? How would anyone know which category went with which bar?? Nevertheless, replace `scale_fill_discrete(name="", guide=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))` with `scale_fill_discrete(guide="none")`

Comment: @ jlhoward, works.I agree with you but my mentor doesn't know what he wants, so then have to add sth., modify, etc.